# Logitech SetPoint doesn't save settings, Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, logitech-mouse, directoryopus

I have a Logitech G5 Laser Mouse. I updated SetPoint from an old version to 6.32.7 (driver version 5.33.10.0), I configured special button settings for some software such as Firefox and Directory Opus, and now **sometimes** when I reboot this settings stop working, even though they seem properly configured at SetPoint. Even if I change something, try to set them again and click apply, the buttons don't have the behavior they should.

I've read some forums where they suggest to unload from startup the KHALMNPR.exe process, but it's not there in this version of SetPoint.

Any ideas?